# X11 forwarding works only with sudo permission

Tags: sshd, x11-forwarding

I have an ubuntu 17.10 system(let's call it **A**). I want to use it from remote machines(**B,C...**). I have tried logging in from windows through putty and MobaXTerm and from other ubuntu machines through `ssh -Y user@ip` too. None of them show any error while connecting. However whenever I want to open any GUI application(**from B,C..**), e.g. `gnome-terminal`, it opens in the my ubuntu system(On **A**) only. But if I give the command `sudo gnome-terminal` it opens in the correct system(on **B,C...**).

P.S. I have a different ubuntu machine which is functioning properly so I copied the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files from there to machine **A**. It didn't help. Still I am facing the same issue.

How to fix this?

P.S. I reinstalled ubuntu while keeping /home as it is. Still the problem persists.

P.P.S. gvim works somehow but all other gui programs don't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to **add** in this line:
`X11UseLocalHost no`

Notice it is setting it to **no**.
then restart the service using `sudo systemctl restart sshd`. You'll have to logon again. This is how I fixed my 17.10 system.

Comment: I had already tested that. Did again. No change in the situation.